# How to set SashForm children default sizes

Tags: java, forms, resize, widget, swt

I have a `SashForm`, and the objective is simply to make a form with 2 children:

- a table
- a side-menu for performing operations on the table

The widths can be adjusted but I want to set an aesthetically-pleasing default.

I want the table to be larger than the side menu when the form is loaded, something like a 75:25 ratio (currently the ratio is 50:50, which makes the side-menu way too big).

I've tried absolutely everything to get the children to change size, but they simply won't do a thing. I've added layouts, I have used absolute positioning, I've toyed around with many different test values in each circumstance. I've looked at it over and over again, but it's no use. No matter what I do, I can't seem to affect the state of this widget or even figure out what the problem is.

```
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout()); //stretch the form to fill the window
    sf = new SashForm(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,false);

    sf.setLayout(gl);

    fillComp = new Composite(sf, SWT.NONE);   //child 1: spreadsheet data
    opComp = new Composite (sf, SWT.BORDER);  //child 2: user operation panel
    opComp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    GridData gd1 = new GridData(
            2, //test values - could be 200000 and it wouldn't make a difference
            2  //
            );

    GridData gd2 = new GridData(
            1, //test values
            1  //
            );


    //gd1.horizontalSpan = 2;  //blablabla
    //gd2.horizontalSpan = 1;  //all do nothing
    //gd1.minimumWidth = 600;    //tested a variety of variables, setting them
    //gd2.minimumWidth = 200;    //to a variety of values

    fillComp.setLayoutData(gd1);
    opComp.setLayoutData(gd2);

    sf.pack();        //these do nothing
    fillComp.pack();  //
    opComp.pack();    //
```

And I have a listener attached to `fillComp`, on event, it activates this:

```
    try {
        displayTable.setBounds(fillComp.getClientArea());
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
```

The listener can be removed and it doesn't affect the width of the two widgets.

I could post a half a dozen different code blocks, all of which have failed to even make the layout change in the slightest. I could change the parent's layout, but that just makes this layout much smaller but still quite equally-unalterable.

Please provide insight if you can. I've read all the tutorials and code snippets, but absolutely nothing makes a difference to this one particular widget.

P.S. This gives an error:

```
sf.setWeights(new int[] { 3, 1 });
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
> ```

Comment: Try [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SashFormExample.htm) code example. `setWeight(int[])` is the way to go.

Comment: Previously I'd tried SetWeight(int[]) but it would inexplicably give an error. I'd avoided using this but I gave it another shot. I realized that perhaps calling it before the children had been added was what was causing the error. My hunch was right. It's actually pretty horrible that this was the source of the error, since I wasn't expecting it to behave so procedurally.

Comment: Well, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yes, definitely. It was quite the frustrating conundrum. This experience transformed me as a programmer. It transformed me from a novice programmer into a raging baboon.

Comment: Welcome to the world of GUI programming ;)

Answer (score -2):

sum of elements of int[] in sf.setWeights() should be equals to 100,
in your example it should be{75, 25}